# Android HTTPS Progressive Streaming in Honeycomb 3.1 3.2

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-mediaplayer, google-tv

According to this page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Android 3.1 and 3.2 should support `HTTPS` progressive streaming, but I am having a hard time finding out how to do so because `setDataSource` for `MediaPlayer` only takes `http`/`rtsp`. Is there a workaround to stream `HTTPS` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question #google-tv, I can say for certain that on #google-TV, https does not work for HLS on the current and last several versions.

If you'd like to secure your content, send a cookie with the initial key, then use AES w/ rotating keys for your segments.  To set the initial cookie for verification, you'll need to use reflection to set your cookies in a videoView.

Comment: I understand that https HLS is not supported but how about https progressive download? will it be supported?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Honeycomb** is closed-source and released under NDA. Hence, it may not be possible to discuss Honeycomb's sources in a public forum due to legal restrictions.

However, the subsequent `AOSP` release i.e. **Ice-cream Sandwich** a.k.a. **ICS** has derived a lot of features from Honeycomb and hence, I am phrasing my answer based on the same.

From [`MediaPlayer.java`](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) sources, I do agree with your observation on support for `http` or `rtsp` only as observed from [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#820). However, from the player engine implementation, we can observe that `https` is also supported as can be observed from [`AwesomePlayer::finishSetDataSource`](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#1959). I presume you would have considered the intent related dependencies for `http` download already.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
```

In a nutshell, I feel `https` may already be supported by the platform.